# VBS error Overflow: 'WScript.Sleep'. A script to be an Alarm

Tags: vbscript

I've written this and I keep getting the same errors and I dont know why but in the test vbs file it works fine?

What its supposed to do is take a number so for 9AM you'd enter 9 and convert it into seconds then add it to the time it would take to get to midnight by taking the current time in seconds from 86400 which is 24*60*60. The math checks out, I just don't understand what this error means or can spot a mistake.

Here's the test, that works.

```
Dim sglTimer

usertime = InputBox("What time? (in hours from 12)")
usersectime = usertime * 60 * 60
sglTimer = timer
tf = 86400
timeaway = tf-timer
totimeaway = usersectime + timeaway
mstotimeaway = totimeaway * 1000
WScript.Sleep mstotimeaway
MsgBox("woop")
```

And here's the what's supposed to be fully functional, but I keep getting that sleep error.

```
Option Explicit
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim sglTimer
Dim batName
Dim statusCode
Dim returntext
Dim isitok
Dim usertime
Dim usersectime
Dim tf
Dim timeaway
Dim totimeaway
Dim mstotimeaway

returntext = InputBox("What time do you wish to wake up at", "How long?", "60", 150, 150)

If IsNumeric(returntext) Then
    isitok = MsgBox("Is " & returntext & " minuites OK?", vbOKCancel)
    returntext = returntext * 1000 * 60
    If isitok = 1 Then
        usertime = returntext
        usersectime = usertime * 60 * 60
        sglTimer = timer
        tf = 86400
        timeaway = tf-timer
        totimeaway = usersectime + timeaway
        mstotimeaway = totimeaway * 1000
        MsgBox("Started coutdown, in the background.")
        WScript.Sleep mstotimeaway

        WshShell.SendKeys("^{Esc}")
        WScript.Sleep 1000
        WshShell.SendKeys("chrome")
        WScript.Sleep 2000
        WshShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
        WScript.Sleep 10000
        WshShell.SendKeys("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VRDEWANy6P8")
        WScript.Sleep 1000
        WshShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
        WScript.Sleep 1000
    Else
        batName = "C:\Users\The_SUDO\Desktop\ALARM!!!.vbs"
        statusCode = WshShell.Run(batName, 1, True)
    End If
Else
    batName = "C:\Users\The_SUDO\Desktop\ALARM!!!.vbs"
    statusCode = WshShell.Run(batName, 1, True)
End If
```

Comment: What input are you expecting? The question says an hour value (9AM) but the code seems to be wanting minutes. `returntext*1000*60` will convert minutes to milliseconds.

Comment: ah yeah thats an error ill see if its a fix later.Thanks

Comment: Not related to the error, but in my experience `WScript.Sleep` is not very reliable for larger timespans. Short sleeps in a loop until a time limit usually worked better for me. Also, any particular reason why you want to implement the scheduling yourself instead of using the Task Scheduler for it?

Comment: That's a very good point haha thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you transform user input twice:

```vb
returntext = returntext * 1000 * 60
```

```vb
usertime = returntext
usersectime = usertime * 60 * 60
```

`WScript.Sleep` has a max value depending on the scripting host version. You probably exceed that max by multiplying by 1000 twice.

Comment: yeah I think the sleep function doesn't allow for it even when the calculation is once haha I mean I was tired whilst making it so I didn't think about it too much. i guess I could have used one of those ping sleep loops but thanks for your reply :)